# Access secure website using winhttp . TLS 1.3

Tags: c++, web, winapi

I have the following code that works with SSL sites like microsoft.com
but not with [www.dmo.gov.uk](http://www.dmo.gov.uk).
When I open the site using chrome I can see that it requires TLS 1.3
But when I open this side from my Android phone it falls back on using 1.2
Is there any header or another way to force website to negotiate TLS 1.2 when I access it using Winhttp.

```
#include <iostream>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winhttp.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")

static void APIENTRY StatusCallback(
    HINTERNET handle, 
    DWORD_PTR context, 
    DWORD status,
    LPVOID info, 
    DWORD size) {
    handle;
    DWORD err = 0;
    if (status == WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_SECURE_FAILURE) {
        err = *(DWORD*)info;
        printf("Error flags %#010x\n", err);
    }
}

int main()
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
    BOOL bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET hSession = NULL;
    HINTERNET hConnect = NULL;
    HINTERNET hRequest = NULL;
    BOOL ret = FALSE;

    hSession = WinHttpOpen(
        L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    DWORD secure_protocols =
        WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_SSL3 
        | WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1_3;

    ret = ::WinHttpSetOption(
        hSession, 
        WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURE_PROTOCOLS, 
        &secure_protocols,
        sizeof(secure_protocols));

    WinHttpSetStatusCallback(
        hSession, 
        StatusCallback,
        WINHTTP_CALLBACK_FLAG_ALL_NOTIFICATIONS, 0);

    if (hSession)
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect(
            hSession,
            L"www.dmo.gov.uk",
            // L"www.microsoft.com",
            INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0);

    if (hConnect)
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(
            hConnect, L"GET", NULL,
            NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
            WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
            WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

    DWORD dwFlags = SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA
        | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_WRONG_USAGE
        | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
        | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID;

    ret = WinHttpSetOption(
        hRequest, 
        WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, 
        (void *)&dwFlags, 
        sizeof(dwFlags));
    if (FALSE == ret) {
        printf("Error %u in WinHttpSetOption.\n", GetLastError());
    }

    // Send a request.
    if (hRequest) {
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(
            hRequest,
            WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
            0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 
            0, 0, 0);
    }
    // End the request.
    if (bResults)
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(
            hRequest, nullptr);

    // Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
    if (bResults)
        do
        {
            // Check for available data.
            dwSize = 0;
            if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize))
                printf("Error %d in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n", GetLastError());

            // Allocate space for the buffer.
            pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize + 1];
            if (!pszOutBuffer)
            {
                printf("Out of memory\n");
                dwSize = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // Read the Data.
                ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1);

                if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,
                    dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
                    printf("Error %d in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError());
                else
                    printf("%s\n", pszOutBuffer);

                // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
                delete[] pszOutBuffer;
            }

        } while (dwSize > 0);

        // Report any errors.
        if (!bResults)
            printf("Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError());

        // Close any open handles.
        if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
        if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
        if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
}
```

Comment: use `WinHttpSetOption`  for set `WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURE_PROTOCOLS` to `WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1_2` or what version you need

Comment: Edited the code. Did not work

Comment: i use WinHttpSetOption  on hSession and this is worked ok

Comment: You mean exactly the same code as this? Did you try WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1_3 and the site www.dmo.gov.uk

Comment: no, i also can not got response for exactly this site (desptite same my code work for another sites). if i use direct schanel over sockets (not winhttp) too. but error is different. if i not set protocol - i got 0x80090326 error (*The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.*). if i set some protocol bits - error is 0x80090302
*The function requested is not supported*. and windows not support `SP_PROT_TLS1_3_CLIENT`

Comment: Windows side: the tls 1.3 is not available in all windows version. You could refer to the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-

According to the Doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/option-flags?redirectedfrom=MSDN  `WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1_3` is still not officially documented in the windows api.

Comment: @Jeaninez. I used Windows SDK 10.0.0.22.

Comment: @RbMm As I mentioned in the question I can access this site from my Android phone and when I am using Android the site uses TLS 1.2.  So maybe there is a way to allow this kind of downgrade using winhttp? Maybe user-agent header?

Comment: When i set tls version to 1.2 i got error the function requested  is not supported

Comment: @RbMm . Same here. But since Android Chrome can do it I guess server configuration supports it . So it should be possible,

Comment: May be. But i don't know another way